# Standard software for producing video with AR effect

Tags: effects, 3d, tracking

What is a standard tool to make videos that contain AR effect?

I am very impressed with this movie because (a) it tracks the camera position of 3D coordinates smoothly and (b) gadgets of Mac OS are clearly placed with nice look.

I think AR is the future in front of us, so, eager to produce this kind of video by myself to feel how we see with it!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to obtain such a result. You can record a video and add these objects using editing software like after effects or blender. This software can track the surfaces and you can add any 3d objects. The second way is to build an AR app using unity or an unreal engine. This method is good and you can use this with any surfaces, unlike the first method. You can find out more from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yQKJkGenTnA)